# how to get phpVersion.php and phpMyAdmin working with the php version 7 on my apache server

Tags: apache-http-server, php

My `phpVersion.php` file is showing me:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

So it looks like it's not recognising the `php` on my server. My `PhpMyAdmin` isn't working either.

When I do `php -v` on my server I see:

```
PHP 7.0.30-1+ubuntu14.04
```

So, it looks like I have `version 7.0.30` on my server.

How can I get my `phpVersion.php` to show `version 7`, and to get `PhpMyAdmin` working again?

I tried `sudo a2enmod php7.0.30` on the command line but I get the message

```
Module php7.0.30 does not exist !
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `loadmodule` for PHP in your Apache config? Something like `LoadModule php7_module "c:/php7/php7apache2_4.dll"` in `httpd.conf`

Comment: Hey, I think I found the answer. Will post as answer if it works for me, tx for your help.

Comment: This post fixed it for me, just follow the instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057615/ubuntu-apache-module-php7-does-not-exist